# What is the best way to design GUI on ARM cortex-M microcontrollers?

Tags: arm, keil, st, user-interface

STM currently supplemented emWin for free, but it got a Win98-ish style which is not very user friendly. Is it possible to use qt to design UI? What are the recommended approaches?

Comment: I don't think you can fit qt on a cortex-M, unless you have some big external flash and RAM. Do you have an idea of the size of this library? And its dependencies?

Comment: Nearly evey question that asks for a 'best' without giving a definition for it is too broad and/or asks for opinions. On top of that, this question doesn't even give the slightest hint about the kind of UI. 1x16 char LCD with two pusbuttons? Or 320x640 color LCD with touch? Hence vote to close.

Comment: I'm currently working on stm32f746-discovery board. My question is about the options I'm having for GUI, since I've heard some professionals have used qt for embedded design but I can't find a source on how.

Comment: @AliA QT is for Cortex-A series not Cortex-M series. if you want a cute GUI you can either edit it or design/write another one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434280/what-is-qt-bare-metal) from two years ago, it is not possible to run QT framework without an OS.

If emWin is too ugly for you, you may be able to write your own widgets for it, beautifying it more, or you could roll your own which I imagine is popular with people who are picky about look-and-feel at this level of hardware.